# why do i need to restart my docker container to see changes in django views.py file on windows

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Why do I have to restart my docker container every time I make a change in my Django python files? I'm running a Django app via Docker and it seems any changes I make in my  Views(and possibly elsewhere) are not reflected until I restart my container.

For example, if I log an output to the terminal or make changes, then refresh, there's no change. If I restart my container and then refresh, I get the result I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can consider Docker environment like **immutable** type doesn’t allow any change in the object once it has been created.

And that will give us more security.
If you want a solution there is some vs code extensions can run script contain some command after you edit your files, you can insert **docker** command in this script to reload environment after you edit any file.

Comment: alternatively, you can connect to the container and directly make changes there, instead of the source files, but this will add extra steps to then copy the changes to the source files once you want to push the changes.